# How can I tell Chrome or Firefox to run Javascript or load a Bookmarklet from the commandline?

Tags: css, firefox, google-chrome

Is it possible to, from the command line, tell Chrome or Firefox to run javascript in the currently open browser window?  Or alternatively, load a bookmarklet that contains javascript?

I'd like to have a program that watches for changes to a css file, and when the css file updates, the browser window would automatically load the new css file.  I've setup a javascript bookmarklet to do this, but I'd love to have it done automatically whenever the css file updates.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In Firefox this definitely won't be possible without an extension, don't know about Chrome. The command line can open a javascript: URL but this code will run in its own tab, without access to the page you are currently viewing. So an extension would need to implement `nsICommandLineHandler` interface (see https://developer.mozilla.org/en/Chrome/Command_Line for an example) and handle some command line flag. It would then use `nsIWindowWatcher.getMostRecentWindow("navigator:browser")` to get the current browser window and do `window.gBrowser.contentWindow.location.href = "javascript:..."` to run the bookmarklet on the current tab.

Answer (score 0):

For FF: The source code to this may help: https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/css-refresh-199425/

Comment: Unlikely - the main "difficulty" here would be the command line handler but the extension you link to doesn't have one (and no XPCOM components in general).